# FFMPEG: max size for adelay parameter

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

Command with large size `adelay` parameter throws an error

```
Delay must be non negative number.
Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_adelay_1
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:1
```

The command is:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a]adelay=55555555:all=1[a0];[a0]amix=inputs=1[a]" -map [a] out.mp3
```

How can this be solved? What's the max size for `adelay` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a limitation. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9196

It was fixed on April 25 2021, so you'll need a later git build. Or you can use the workaround in the ticket comment #3